# responsive-calendar: get date on event onMonthChange

Tags: calendar, responsive

I'm using a calendar from http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/.
I´d like to get the date on event onMonthChange.
But the year, month  and day are always undefined.

The documentation of the plugin is well made  but doesnt explains how to do it by example.

Here is my event:

```
onMonthChange: function(events) { 
         var $year=$(this).data('year'); //here I get undefined
         var $month=$(this).data('month');//here I get undefined 
         var $day=1; //but I´d like to get the day of the current date after changed
    },
```

if I use this event from documentation always works well:

```
onDayClick: function(events) { 
         var thisDayEvent, key;

         key = $(this).data('year')+'-'+addLeadingZero( $(this).data('month') )+'-'+addLeadingZero( $(this).data('day') );
      }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation your are showing applies to day events.

When using `onMonthChange`, there is no event argument, and in order to access the object, use `$(this)[0]`. That gives you access to the new selected Month through the properties `currentMonth` and `currentYear` (see code):

```js
 $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({ onMonthChange: function() {
 alert(($(this)[0].currentMonth + 1) +  '/' + $(this)[0].currentYear );
            } });
```

Please note that this uses the javascript getMonth(), so the months will be 0-11.